# We are unable to validate your information. Please try again

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to implement in my CI project this code:
http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php/comment-page-2#comments

But i get this error, when i try to login  with my sandbox account.
"We are unable to validate your information. Please try again."

I configured the config.php with the right credential and i try to login with another sandbox account.

Why i get this error?

Comment: That's probably an issue you should take up with PayPal.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing... on a page that was working! I think it is a PayPal issue... wait for a fix

Comment: I will wait... thank you so much

Comment: I am having this problem too, solved it yet @il_maca?

Comment: Yeah, it's a cache problem. Clean it with ccleaner or directly from browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal's sandbox has a bug. Delete your cookies and it will work.

Comment: Surprised this doesn't have a zillion upvotes. Hadn't thought to clear cookies but that solved the problem. Crazy that Paypal's developers still haven't gotten around to fixing this!